# What's the difference between <a asp-page="linkhere"> and <a href="linkhere"> in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is a fundamental question:

What's the real difference between `<a asp-area="" asp-page="/linkhere">test</a>` and classic `<a href="/linkhere">test</a>` in ASP.NET Core?

The end result appears to be the same always (it's an href attribute always in the end)

Does it somehow protect against clickjacking or something similar behind the scenes??

In other words, does using asp-page bring any security advantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customise the routing for Razor Pages, so that your `LinkHere` Razor Page and the URL to the page may be different. In that case, the `asp-page` approach ensures that the URL will match the page, but the `href` approach would need to be updated accordingly.

For an example of how a Razor Page URL can be customised, see [Configure a page route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-a-page-route):

> ```
> options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Contact", "TheContactPage/{text?}");
> ```

In this example, the page `Contact` has a URL of `TheContactPage` with an optional extra segment.